# telegram api contacts.importContacts return empty

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

i have 1800 contact in my telegram account , when i want add more number it's return empty array like below:

```
{"_writeBuffers":null,"_readOffset":828,"_buffer":{"type":"Buffer","data":[21,67,82,173,21,196,181,28,0,0,0,0,21,196,181,28,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...]},"_typeId":"15c4b51c","_typeName":"Vector","module":"api.type","type":"Long","list":["0x0000000000000000","0x0000000000000000"],"_byId":{}},"users":{"_writeBuffers":null,"_readOffset":8,"_buffer":{"type":"Buffer","data":[21,196,181,28,0,0,0,0]},"_typeId":"15c4b51c","_typeName":"Vector","module":"api.type","type":"User","list":[],"_byId":{}}}
```

and cant add contact from telegram mobile or other telegram app with current number,is any limit for that?
how can add more number ?